# .net core application as a service on ubuntu

Tags: .net, mono, nancy

Currently I have a web application that makes use of the NancyFx framework. I run this application on Ubuntu as a service using TopShelf on top of mono. In the last couple of days I've spent time playing with dotnet core and I am looking at moving the existing code to .net core. I'm having trouble finding documentation on how a .net core application can be run as a service, and more particularly an linux service. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A service in **Linux** can just be a regular console application in **.NET Core.**

To have it behaving like a daemon, handling start and stop, you can have a look at this answer:

[Killing gracefully a .NET Core daemon running on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291567/killing-gracefully-a-net-core-daemon-running-on-linux)

You can use **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin** to self host the web application.

ASP.NET Core has its own implementation of **OWIN**:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/owin.html

Comment: Great, this is the answer i did not manage to find on my own :-)

Comment: If this is a useful answer, then you should mark it as such.