# .net core one code for service/daemon for Windows/Linux

Tags: linux, .net-core, windows-services

On Windows there are windows services, on Linux there are daemons.

Is it possible write one code using .net core which works on Windows like a service and on Linux like a daemon? Or I must write different system dependent start code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a Linux daemon from a .NET Core console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000629/how-do-you-create-a-linux-daemon-from-a-net-core-console-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services and *daemons (not demons) are simply ways for the OS to manage executables/scripts, so as long as the code is OS independent (like .NET core) you should be able to use the same code base.

Running an executable as a daemon/service will vary based on the operating system. As such, I've linked to some existing stack overflow questions that should help a little.

[How do you create a Linux daemon from a .NET Core console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000629/how-do-you-create-a-linux-daemon-from-a-net-core-console-application)

[Create Windows service from executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable)

Comment: Thanks for information. I understand there isn't one easy and multiplatform solution :( I have corrected spelling, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See Worker Services (if you can now use .NET Core 3.x):

You can create one from the new Visual Studio 2019 Worker Service project template, or by using the .NET CLI:

`dotnet new worker`

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio