# Topshelf and .net core under linux

Tags: c#, topshelf

I have a simple application that starts as a service using topshelf and it looks simple:

```
 HostFactory.Run(x =>
 {
    x.Service<RequestService>();
    x.RunAsLocalSystem();
 });
```

Well it works, but under windows. When I tried this under Linux I am getting:

> Topshelf.Runtime.Windows.WindowsHostEnvironment Error: 0 : Unable to get parent process (ignored), System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'kernel32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libkernel32.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Has someone came across this problem?
I tried to google it but someone said it works other that it is tool only for windows.

Or maybe there is some other service hoisting framework for .net core?

Comment: WojciechSzabowicz would you like to accept @Paul-Sebastian Manole's answer then? Looks like that's the correct answer to you question, which he took the time to explain

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Topshelf is not advertised as cross-platform and so it does not (or did not at the time of writing) official support .Net Core on non-Windows environments, even if it can run in them (at least at the time of writing, see below).

The solution is to change the environment builder when running on non-Windows hosts.

Here is an example from my project. When creating the service, pick the env builder at runtime based on the host OS.

```cs
HostFactory.Run(c =>
{
  // Change Topshelf's environment builder on non-Windows hosts:
  if (
    RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX) ||
    RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)
  )
  {
    c.UseEnvironmentBuilder(
      target => new DotNetCoreEnvironmentBuilder(target)
    );
  }

  c.SetServiceName("SelloutReportingService");
  c.SetDisplayName("Sellout Reporting Service");
  c.SetDescription(
    "A reporting service that does something...");
  c.StartAutomatically();
  c.RunAsNetworkService();
  c.EnableServiceRecovery(
    a => a.RestartService(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
  );
  c.StartAutomatically();
  c.Service<SelloutReportingService>();
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. [This code](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/blob/03bde8963da8c057ffc6df07ef9600ffdf6047c1/src/Topshelf/Hosts/StartHost.cs#L37-L40) seems to indicate that a Topshelf service will refuse to start if it's not running on Windows. Are you saying that you've been able to get a Topshelf service to run successfully on Linux?

Comment: @InteXX, yes. That is what I showed.

Comment: This is incredibly good news (for me, at least). I can't _begin_ to tell you how good this news is :-)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you installed [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/topshelf) version of Topshelf - you would notice under dependencies that it doesn't support .NET Core and therefore it will not run under a Linux environment.

It will only run under a Windows environment as you mentioned in your post. `kernel32.dll` is a Windows dependency that it cannot find, therefore it cannot run.

Comment: Aye it is 4.2.0, but going throu API of the host factory I came upon UseEnvironmentBuilder (well this method is not described in offical documentation, like it does not exists) in description it says that default value is WindowsHostEnvironmentBuilder, and when i changed that to DotNetCoreEnvironmentBuilder it worked on Linux.

Comment: @WojciechSzabowicz — That's very interesting! I imagine the Topshelf `install` CLI argument doesn't work, though (I found some Windows-only code sprinkled throughout the source—[example](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/blob/03bde8963da8c057ffc6df07ef9600ffdf6047c1/src/Topshelf/Runtime/DotNetCore/DotNetCoreHostEnvironment.cs#L162-L165)). Is this what you're finding as well?